# PHPUnit Selenium Drag and Drop Image?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, phpunit

I'm running a test when the user will going to open a window and select image and drop it is it possible? thanks

Comment: How the user will be dropped? Can you show an example.

Comment: http://i43.tinypic.com/fwpnvb.png

like this one :), do you have any idea? i'm using phpunit/selenium web driver

Answer (score 0):

Drag and Drop from computer files is not possible.

You have two options:

- drag and drop from currently visible files, as explained here: [Selenium2 + phpunit -> drag and drop on xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830113/selenium2-phpunit-drag-and-drop-on-xpath)
- instead of drag and drop, set value of the input to file location. like `$input->value('d:\\1.jpg');`