# Selenium2 + phpunit -> drag and drop on xpath

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I use PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase Selenium and phpunit  and I need make drag and drop one xpath element, on diferent emelent. Like on this screen, to change position on tree (category tree)

Answer (score 2):

```
  $srcDrag=$this->byId('draggable');
  $targetDrop=$this->byId('droppable');
  $stateChecker=$this->byCssSelector('#droppable > p');
  $this->assertEquals("Drop here",$stateChecker->text());


  $this->moveto($srcDrag);
  $this->buttondown();
  $this->moveto($targetDrop);
  $this->buttonup();
```

Answer (score 0):

Drag and Drop from computer files is not possible. In addition to Shahriar's propose, you could also set value of the input to file location.

**`$input->value('d:\\1.jpg');`**